# Proof of Krull's intersection theorem with Taylor expansion

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I asked this question last year in MSE, but I didn't get an answer.

---

I took a commutative algebra course last semester (using Kaplansky's book), and I learned about Krull's intersection theorem. In the course, we proved it without using the Artin-Rees Lemma. I have heard that the standard proof uses the lemma.

Are there any other simple or intuitive proofs for the theorem? I have heard that there is an intuitive reason for coordinate rings in 
[this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109161/a-geometric-insight-into-a-proof-of-krull-intersection-theorem), that *the only function which vanishes to arbitrarily high order at a point is the zero function*. In case of polynomials, this is easy to accept if we consider the polynomial as a Taylor series expansion (with finitely many terms). Using this, I tried to prove it for a local ring, as follows.

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Suppose there exists $D:R\to R$ satisfying $D(ab)=(Da)b+a(Db)$ and $D(a+b)=Da+Db$, that is, it is a derivation on $R$. Define $\mathrm {Poly}(R):=\{r\in R\,| \,D^{k}r=0$ for some $k>0\}$, which means that the set of elements in $R$ on which $D$ behaves as a polynomial.

We check that $\mathrm {Poly}(R)$ is a subring of $R$, and I wonder whether $R=\mathrm {Poly}(R)$. Then I want to *approximate* elements in $R$ via their Taylor expansions, but it was not easy to formalize this. I think that the evaluation map corresponds to quotients by maximal ideal; and then it would be possible to find a function $r^{*}:k\to k$ where $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field and $r^{*}$ is induced by an element $r\in R$.

All these things are possible in the case of polynomial ring, but it is very hard to do it for general Noetherian rings (or Noetherian local rings). I also noticed that there aren't any nontrivial derivations on the  ring $\mathbf{Z}$. Is there a proof that uses these ideas or versions of them?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you may want to know, just in case that you don't already do, that there is a short, neat, slick, and amazingly beautiful proof of Krull's intersection theorem by Hervé Perdry on the AMM: *An Elementary Proof of Krull's Intersection Theorem*, Amer. Math. Monthly **111** (Apr., 2004), No. 4, 356-357.

Comment: Your definition of $\mathrm{Poly}(R)$ depends on $D$ and for different $D$ you may get different subrings. So, even for polynomial rings, you will have to carefully choose your $D$ (Think of Euler derivation). What that would mean for an arbitrary Noetherian ring is anybody's guess.

Comment: To answer your question about whether $\text{Poly}(R) = R$: consider the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, e^x]$ with the derivation $\partial_x$.

Comment: Concerning the OP's statement, "I wonder whether $R = {\rm Poly}(R)$", the answer, of course, is no: Consider the trivial derivation on $R$ mapping everything to $0_R$.

Comment: @SalvoTringali I'll check it later since I don't have any authority to see the paper now. Also, I want to find nontrivial derivation which gives $R=\mathrm{Poly}(R)$.

Comment: @Mohan Yes I agree, and It will be hard to find a canonical way to construct nontrivial derivation for a given (Noetherian, and even local) ring.

Comment: @See-WooLee I think you got an email. ;-) As for the rest, why don't specify *in the OP* that $D$ is a *non-trivial* derivation? Also, your comment sounds like your question is different than what is asked in the OP right now: Do you wonder whether there exists at least one derivation on $R$ such that ${\rm Poly}(R) = R$? Or whether ${\rm Poly}(R) = R$ for every non-trivial derivation $D$ on $R$?

Comment: Whatever the case, let $p$ be a prime number, $R$ the ring of polynomials in one variable $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb F_p$ (the field with $p$ elements), and $D$ *any* derivation on $R$. Then $R$ is Noetherian (you ask for Noetherian rings), and $x^{p-1} \notin {\rm Poly}_D(R)$: If $x^{p-1}=D(f)$ for some $f \in R$ and we write $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$, then $n \ge p$, and we must have $ia_i = 0$ for every $i \in [\![1,n]\!] \setminus \{p\}$ and $pa_p = 1$, which is impossible.